# Javafx- Mouse click event that undoes what the previous mouse click did

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I currently have a 3x3 gridpane of which I add a pane with a white background to each space on the grid.

What I am trying to do is have it so that if a user clicks on one of these spaces, the white pane will change to another color. Then if the user were to click on the space again, the pane would change back to white. If clicked again, then it would change to that color again, and so on.

In short, a click would cause an action, and the next click, and those after it would reverse/undo the previous action.

However, I can only get the initial click to work with this. Everything else I've thought to add to this hasn't worked.

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really has to be a Pane, you could try to write a custom Pane which will make it easier for you to control its behaviour:

```
class MyPane extends Pane{
    private Background standard, other;

    public MyPane(){
        standard = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
        other = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
        this.setBackground(standard);
    }

    public void changeColor(){
        if(this.getBackground().equals(standard){
            this.setBackground(other);
        else{
            this.setBackground(standard);
        }
    }

    public void setBackground(Background bckgrnd){
        this.other = bckgrnd;
}
```

If you use this class instead of a standard Pane, you are able to control the color changing simply via

```
@Override
public void  handle(MouseEvent me){
    myPane.changeColor();
}
```

If you would use the `Rectangle`class, you could use the following code:

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent me){
    if(rectangle.getFill() == standard){
        rectangle.setFill(other);
    }else{
        rectangle.setFill(standard);
    }
```

provided that you defined the 2 Paint variables `standard` and `other`, e.g. :

```
private final Paint standard = Color.WHITE;
private Paint other = Color.RED;
```

see [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html)

Comment: This is a good idea! But no, it doesn't have to be a Pane, I could use rectangles too.

Comment: I added the code for the use of the Rectangle class. If this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted so the question can be seen as closed.